# 'module' object has no attribute 'pcapObject'

Tags: python, packet, packet-capture, pcap

I have the following sample code which doesn't seem to want to run.

```
import pcap
pc = pcap.pcapObject()
dev = sys.argv[1]
pc.open_live(dev, 1600, 0, 100)
pc.setfilter("udp port 53", 0, 0)
while 1:
    pc.dispatch(1, p.pcap_dispatch)
```

I'm really not sure why.  I'm using [pypcap](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/).  I'm running this on both 2.5.1 and 2.6 versions of python (separate machines) using mac osx (leopard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least according to documentation from the project this line:

```
pc = pcap.pcapObject()
```

Should really be:

```
pc = pcap.pcap()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two **pcap** libraries for Python:

- [pypcap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcap)
- [pylibpcap](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pylibpcap/)

Both of them are imported as:

```
import pcap
```

But the following code implies that **pylibpcap** is actually expected, instead of **pypcap**.

```
pcap.pcapObject()
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have python on this Computer, but when i look at the example, it should be

pc = pcap.pcap ()